# rails 5.x: add nofollow to all links in 'sanitize'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a Rails application whose HAML templates frequently make use of a routine called `sanitize`.  I have deduced from context that this routine sanitizes user-controlled HTML.  Example:

```
# views/feed_items/_about.html.haml
%h3 Summary:
.description
  = sanitize @feed_item.description
```

I want to make this routine add 'rel=nofollow' to all outbound links, in addition to what it's already doing.  What is the most straightforward way to do that?

N.B. I am not having any luck finding the definition of this method, or the official configuration knobs for it.  The vendor directory has two different HTML sanitizer gems in it and I can't even figure out which one is being used. This is a large, complicated web application that I did not write, and I barely understand Ruby, let alone all of Rails' extensions to it.  Please assume I do not know any of the things that you think are obvious.

Comment: Are you thinking on "monkey-patch" the sanitize method in order to add the "rel=nofollow"?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Well, ideally there would be a supported mechanism for configuring it, or at least hooking it, but if I have to monkey-patch it that's still better than modifying dozens of HAML files.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution is to use the [`NoFollow`](https://rubydoc.info/github/flavorjones/loofah/main/Loofah/Scrubbers/NoFollow) scrubber already included in Rails. First apply the [default](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) sanitizer, then the specialized scrubber:

```rb
def nofollow(html)
  sanitize(html, scrubber: Loofah::Scrubbers::NoFollow.new)
end

def user_generated_content(html)
  nofollow(sanitize(html))
end
```

Input:

```html
<a onclick="alert()" href="https://example.com/">Example</a>
```

Output:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sanitizer will strip out the `rel` tags if they exist.

I ran into a similar issue and added an additional helper method - `clean_links` to the `ApplicationHelper` module, and called it **after** sanitizing the content.

```
# application_helper.rb
def clean_links html
  html.gsub!(/\<a href=["'](.*?)["']\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/mi, '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\2</a>')
  html.html_safe
end
```

This method looks for all `<a>` tags, and adds rel="nofollow". The `html_safe` method is necessary or else the HTML will be displayed as a string (it's already been sanitized).

This solution treats all links equally, so if you only want this for links pointing outside the domain, you'll have to update the REGEX accordingly.

In your view: `<%= clean_links sanitize(@something) %>`

So, first the content is sanitized, then you add the rel="nofollow" tag before displaying the link.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there's a built-in way:

```rb
sanitize "your input", scrubber: Loofah::Scrubbers::NoFollow.new
```

Comment: This only adds `nofollow` to links, but removes completely the HTML sanitization! You can easily reproduce a XSS attack.

Comment: Alone, yes, but you can trivially [chain](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/tree/v2.19.1#chaining-scrubbers) it with the default sanitizer.